# How can I give dates as rownames to a data frame from quantmod::getSymbols?

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse, quantmod

How can I convert the output from `getSymbols` to have dates as rownames? Here is my code so far.

```
library("quantmod")
library("coindeskr")
getSymbols("AAPL")
> [1] "AAPL"
row.names(head(Cl(AAPL)))
> NULL
btc <- get_historic_price(start = "2017-01-01")
row.names(head(btc))
> [1] "2017-01-01" "2017-01-02" "2017-01-03" "2017-01-04" "2017-01-05" "2017-01-06"
```

Comment: What dates would you like to set the row names to? In your example, the output of `getSymbols()` is only a single element.

Comment: The dates coming from this output> head(Cl(AAPL))
           AAPL.Close
2007-01-03   11.97143
2007-01-04   12.23714
2007-01-05   12.15000
2007-01-08   12.21000
2007-01-09   13.22429
2007-01-10   13.85714

Comment: Yes, then your output of `getSymbols()` must be the same length. You can't set the row names of a column consisting of a single element to a vector containing 6 different strings. Could you describe what you're looking for in more detail?

Comment: coindeskr::get_historic_price() currently gives values of bitcoin related currency only. and quantmod::getSymbols() will give for all stocks. I want the output of getSymbols() to be converted to the format/dataframe of get_historic_price . Plz check responses of head(btc) and head(Cl(AAPL))

Comment: @MarcusCampbell I am trying to apply this code https://github.com/amrrs/anomaly_detection_tidy_way/blob/master/anomalize.R   for common stocks like AAPL etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The creators of anomalize have another package which you might find useful. It's called [tidyquant](http://www.business-science.io/code-tools/2017/01/01/tidyquant-introduction.html) and is perfect for what you are looking to do.

```
library(anomalize)
library(tidyquant)
library(tidyverse)
```

The Tidy Way to get Financial data

```
aapl <- tq_get("AAPL")
```

Referencing your end goal, we can chart AAPL's anomalies since 2008.

```
aapl %>% 
 time_decompose(adjusted) %>%
 anomalize(remainder) %>%
 time_recompose() %>%
 plot_anomalies(time_recomposed = TRUE, ncol = 3, alpha_dots = 0.5)
```

Comment: Epic! This is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 3):

The values of stock-prices in quantmod are not really either data.frames or matrices although they are built from components that have matrix structures and they are somewhat similar to `zoo`-objects:

```
str(AAPL)
#---------
An ‘xts’ object on 2007-01-03/2018-05-01 containing:
  Data: num [1:2852, 1:6] 12.3 12 12.3 12.3 12.3 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:6] "AAPL.Open" "AAPL.High" "AAPL.Low" "AAPL.Close" ...
  Indexed by objects of class: [Date] TZ: UTC
  xts Attributes:  
List of 2
 $ src    : chr "yahoo"
 $ updated: POSIXct[1:1], format: "2018-05-02 16:49:23"
```

So the AAPL object has a numeric matrix called "Data" and a separate index of class Date:

```
> str( index(AAPL) )
 Date[1:2852], format: "2007-01-03" "2007-01-04" "2007-01-05" "2007-01-08" "2007-01-09" "2007-01-10" "2007-01-11" "2007-01-12" ...
> str( coredata(AAPL) )
 num [1:2852, 1:6] 12.3 12 12.3 12.3 12.3 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:6] "AAPL.Open" "AAPL.High" "AAPL.Low" "AAPL.Close" ...
```

You need to learn the structure and the special functions needed to access them cleanly. Look at:

```
 ?xts
 ?xtsAttributes
```

I suspect you may want to try coercion to a dataframe object:

```
str( as.data.frame(AAPL) )
#--------
'data.frame':   2852 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ AAPL.Open    : num  12.3 12 12.3 12.3 12.3 ...
 $ AAPL.High    : num  12.4 12.3 12.3 12.4 13.3 ...
 $ AAPL.Low     : num  11.7 12 12.1 12.2 12.2 ...
 $ AAPL.Close   : num  12 12.2 12.2 12.2 13.2 ...
 $ AAPL.Volume  : num  309579900 211815100 208685400 199276700 837324600 ...
 $ AAPL.Adjusted: num  8.1 8.28 8.23 8.27 8.95 ...

row.names( as.data.frame(AAPL) )[:16]
#---------
   [1] "2007-01-03" "2007-01-04" "2007-01-05" "2007-01-08" "2007-01-09" "2007-01-10" "2007-01-11" "2007-01-12"
   [9] "2007-01-16" "2007-01-17" "2007-01-18" "2007-01-19" "2007-01-22" "2007-01-23" "2007-01-24" "2007-01-25"
```

Comment: Thanks for your help